# thegraph Unable to synchronize after deployment

Tags: ethereum, thegraph

error :Subgraph instance failed to run: A matching Ethereum network with NodeCapabilities { archive: false, traces: true } was not found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Xjt.png)

Redeploy a Subgraph to the Hosted Service

graph deploy --product hosted-service xxx/xxx

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.